How much can we control a birational locus for Chow’s lemma
Let $X$ be a smooth proper complex variety. By Chow’s lemma, there exists a surjective birational morphism $X’\to X$ with $X’$ projective.
My question is the following: take a closed point $x \in X$. Can we take a surjective birational morphism $f$ as above so that $x$ is in an open subset where $f$ is an isomorphism?
I believe this is same as asking if for any closed point $x\in X$, there exists an affine open cover $\{U_i\}$ such that $x\in \cap U_i$, but I cannot figure out a sufficient condition on $X$ for the existence of such a cover for each closed point (except for $X$ being projective or too strong assumption on the automorphism group of $X$) nor a counterexample of $X$ with a closed without such covers.
Thank you in advance.

I think your guess is reasonable but we can take it more precisely. If you look back at the proof of the Chow lemma then a birational locus can be given by taking intersection of dense affine charts.
